# xCode6 How to lock iOS 7.1 devices in portrait programmatically?

Tags: ios8, autolayout, xcode6, uistoryboard, size-classes

I have an xCode6 project that uses storyboards, autolayout and size classes. Deployment target of this project is iOS 7.1 .  I'm using the following size classes:

- Any/Any for portrait iPhone
- Compact Height/Any width for landscape

I noticed that when deployed to iOS 7.1, the device ignores size class related constraints, instead using "Any/Any" only. I don't want to create a separate storyboard for iOS 7.1 only, so I want to lock iOS 7.1 devices in portrait mode. It seems to me that this will require some sort of conditional compilation statement for iOS 7.1, but I'm not sure where to put it.

**How do I modify my project to lock all controllers in portrait mode for iOS 7.1?**

Comment: i added sample projects and screens

Answer (score 1):

**It's not good to lock screen for particular iOS version** but as you asked below code will defiantly help you.

**Code**`(write this code in appdelegate.m)`

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    // Support all orientation
    if(floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1)
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
    // Support only portrait
    else
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```

**Demo project**
[Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xzimbpm5lzqjsx5/demoOrientaion.zip?dl=0)

**Output**
If `iOS > iOS7.1` support all orientation
[image]

If `iOS <= iOS7.1` support only portrait
[image]